# BFS stops after the starting vertex's neighbors have been visited

Tags: c++11, breadth-first-search, maze

I'm attempting to implement a BFS search on a maze, specifically the Apollo and Diana maze puzzle. Upon running my BFS algorithm the initial neighbors of the starting vertex are added however subsequent neighbors are added causing the algorithm to terminate after three iterations when run using the example maze below. The code for my algorithm is:

```
BFS_Algo(){

NodeQueue.push(NodeMatrix[0][0]);


while( !NodeQueue.empty() )
{
    Node current;
    current = NodeQueue.front();
    NodeQueue.pop();

    if( !current.visited )
    {
        current.visited = true;

        for ( int i = 0; i < current.neighbors.size(); ++i )
        {
            if ( !current.neighbors[i].visited )
            {
                NodeQueue.push(current.neighbors[i]);
                current.neighbors[i].predecessor = &NodeMatrix[current.x][current.y];
            }
        }
    }
}



}
```

I know that the neighbors vectors are properly filled since I have a helper function that prints the contents of all the vectors like so:

```
B E:  |R SE|R SW|
R SE: |empty vector
R SW: |B N|B N|
R SE: |B E|
B N:  |R SE|
R E:  |empty vector
B N:  |R SE|
B E:  |O O|
O O:  |empty vector
```

/*empty vectors signify that there are no neighbors.*/

I don't believe this to be a logical error, but I feel this might be more in line with local references instead. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
**Additional Info:**
Ive read in the information for the graph from a file similar to this example:

```
B E |R SE|R SW|
R SE|B N |R E |
B N |B E |O O |
```

I have created a class that contains a node struct that holds all the appropriate data.

```
private:

struct Node{

    int x;                          position in graph
    int y;                          position in graph
    std::string color;              graph attr
    std::string direction;          graph attr
    bool visited;                   bfs bool
    Node * predecessor;             ancestor for path backtracking
    std::vector<Node> neighbors;    vector of neighbors

};

short rows;
short columns;
Node **NodeMatrix;
std::queue<Node> NodeQueue;
```

Comment: `!current.neighbors[i].visited` doesn't look valid, since `neighbors` does not store pointers to actual Nodes, but copies of the nodes from `NodeMatrix`

Comment: indeed its not properly adjusting this variable, what would be an appropriate solution? a vector of pointers? EDIT: implemented that and that aspect is now functioning properly, however discovered a problem within my print path function

Comment: I usually store a graph in `vector<vector<int>> g;`, which holds indices `0...N-1` to some nodes collection, e.g., `vector<Node> G(N);`, so when I know that a neightbour of `g[0]` is e.g., `g[0][0]=2`, then its node is stored in `G[2]`